# Adobe ActiveX loads blank thumbnailed PDF's

Tags: delphi, pdf, activex, delphi-xe2, adobe-reader

I'm using the AcroPDF ActiveX Library through Delphi XE2

All I do is call `myPDFThing.LoadFile('Peter''s 2011 State Taxes.pdf');`

and I get:

[image: My Taxes]

There are a few seemingly useless options for adobe reader ActiveX control, but none of them fix this particular inconvenience.  It also makes the page preview you see when scrolling through the pages blank.  The solution, [apparently](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3788772) is to use an older version of Reader.

I did notice, if I open the self-same tax document in Firefox, I do get all the previewed panes and the scrollbar preview that shows up in the ActiveX control does not even show up.

So, what is Adobe doing in Firefox that I can't do in Delphi?

Obviously they've got some capability we I can't yet tap into.  I'm just wondering how Firefox, being open source, embeds adobe reader the way I want to embed it and where is the code, in the Firefox source, that embeds Adobe Reader - is that closed source stuff from Adobe?

Comment: Possibly an Adobe problem: http://forums.adobe.com/message/3788772

Comment: @Mike that about sums it up (can't believe I didn't find that link in the adobe forums, I spent a few hours researching it)

Comment: If you've found an answer to your question, you should either post the answer (in which case, you can accept it yourself as being correct) so that it's helpful to others, or delete your question. (It's better if you provide an answer, though - as I said, it can help others in the future who experience the same problem.)